# If statements in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle

Is it possible in Oracle to put conditional IF statements in the WHERE clause?

I want to filter all rows with an end date before today. And if the end date is empty, it should not filter on it. I've tried this:

```
SELECT discount_amount 
FROM vw_ph_discount_data 
WHERE sysdate > start_date
AND
    IF 
        end_date IS NOT EMPTY 
    THEN 
        sysdate < end_date
```

But I get "invalid relational operator".

Comment: Not getting your qw. There must be some document in which this is explained. Whether or not it is allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if(condition, then, else) in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428402/ifcondition-then-else-in-oracle). There are lots of other questions related to `IF - ELSE` clauses (or more specifically `CASE - WHEN`) in Oracle...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT discount_amount 
FROM vw_ph_discount_data 
WHERE sysdate > start_date
AND sysdate < nvl(end_date,sysdate+1)
```

Comment: Yes, right up to the point where your DBMS drops to its knees under the load :-) It may not matter for small databases (which is probably what this is, admittedly) but we have to handle true behemoths, where per-row functions in queries have to be seriously justified - too much performance can be destroyed by them.

Comment: @paxdiablo NVL is implemented in RDBMS engine, it is not PL/SQL. PL/SQL functions combined with SQL can destroy SQL performance.

Comment: No, any query that has to grab a lot of records, then modify one of the columns, can destroy performance. This includes NVL(), COALESCE, and all those things. It's almost always better to reduce the cardinality of your queries earlier in the process (such as in the where filters).

Comment: I think we've probably discussed this to death by now - the comment sections are starting to warn me about extended discussions.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's possible, it's not a good idea. Per-row functions will destroy performance.

In this case, the best way is to probably just union two exclusive queries:

```
SELECT discount_amount 
    FROM vw_ph_discount_data 
    WHERE sysdate > start_date
    AND   end_date IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT discount_amount 
    FROM vw_ph_discount_data 
    WHERE sysdate > start_date
    AND   end_date IS NOT NULL
    AND   sysdate < end_date
```

(changed to `NULL` from `EMPTY` since that seems to be what you were after).

Assuming `end_date` is indexed, this should scream along even though it's two queries. Having to do some extra processing on each and every row returned is rarely a good idea.

Whatever methods you choose to investigate, benchmark them with real world data. The prime directive of optimisation is *measure, don't guess.*

Comment: this is not efficient. In general will scan target rows twice.

Comment: @Florin, no it won't, the queries are exclusive of each other. The IS/IS-NOT separation guarantees that. I've done a great deal of testing on exactly this sort of stuff and it's almost always faster that the doSomeFunctionOn(Column) alternatives.

Comment: IS NOT EMPTY is not valid in Oracle

Comment: @Florin, please send through some of whatever you're smoking: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions013.htm

Comment: "Use the IS [NOT] EMPTY conditions to test whether a specified **nested table** is empty". It does not refer to column values.

Comment: You are right in the union all with exclusive queries aspect. But this case is a little bit different. `end_date is null union end_date is not null` is not purely complementary in Oracle.

Comment: @FlorinGhita, which value of `end_date` in Oracle is both NULL and NOT NULL at the same time? It seems to me that would be a serious breakage in Oracle, though not _that_ surprising given its inability to tell the difference between NULLs and empty strings in some cases :-)

Comment: They are mathematicaly complementary, an also in ORacle logic. But in a query, in most cases the engine will to two full scans. Even an FBI(function based index) won't help too much, because there are some other conditions in the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that if-else statements can be used in pure Sql code. You need to use **stored procedure** to achieve your aim. I suppose in your case you can use the code below:

```
DECLARE
  DATE end_date
BEGIN
  IF end_date IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT discount_amount 
    FROM vw_ph_discount_data 
    WHERE sysdate > start_date AND sysdate < end_date;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: My intuition say that end_date is a column in the table `vw_ph_discount_data`

Comment: I suppose you are right, Florin. I just wanted to give the basic idea of sp anyway. If he initializes the end_date variable with a simple select statement in the beginning of the procedure body, above code would work then.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do this:

```
SELECT discount_amount 
FROM vw_ph_discount_data 
WHERE sysdate > start_date
AND (end_date IS EMPTY OR sysdate < end_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `IF` statement to create multiple queries or try `WHERE (end_date IS NULL OR end_date > SYSDATE)`.

Not sure if you should use `IS [NOT] EMPTY` on "end_date". See [IS EMPTY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions013.htm).